# query to find how many times one person buy, in one years

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

Hi all i have one table(shop) with 3 columns:

`id     receipt_number   receipt_date
 111    666              02/02/2016
 111    666              02/02/2016
 111    667              02/03/2016
 112    668              02/02/2016
 112    669              03/02/2015
 112    670              04/12/2015
 113    671              05/11/2013`

i want query to find how many times every id have bought in the last year.
final table:

```
id      bought
111     2
112     2

111 have 2 shop because in database have 2 equals receipt
112 have 2 shop because in database one shop It is a year old
113 there is not because the only shop it has been done years ago.
```

for now i have do this:

`SELECT DISTINCT(id),receipt_number,receipt_date
FROM shop
where receipt_number in (SELECT distinct(receipt_number)
FROM shop)
GROUP BY(id)`
but is completly wrong

thanks all and sorry for my bad english

i have found the result, thanks all

`select id, count(*)shop_number
from
(select id,recipt_Date,recipt_number
from shop
where id !='' and recipt_date > DATE_ADD(sysdate(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) 
and recipt_Date <= sysdate() 
group by id, recipt_date , recipt_nu,ber) as a
group by id`

Comment: want to find data for current year?

Comment: not current year but in the last years from today

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT receipt_number)
FROM  shop
WHERE receipt_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `group by`, `where`, and `count(distinct)`:

```
select id, count(distinct receipt_number)
from shop
where receipt_date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 year)
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server query could be

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM  shop
WHERE convert(datetime, receipt_date, 101) BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
GROUP BY id, receipt_number
```

Comment: this function is wrong, because my date type is string

Comment: in that case you can simply convert your receipt_date to datetime datatype using `convert(datetime, receipt_date, 101)`